# How to run swagger APi on Multiple projects using apache karaf

Tags: web-services, cxf, swagger, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have created Java RESTFUL web services using Apache karaf, I am using swagger for API documentation.All Annotation are applied and its running successfully on single project with the general swagger configuration(Swagger core and annotation jar are there on each project) but when i try to run the swagger API on multiple project using apache karaf it cached the first project json and always return the cached json. Swagger core dependencies are located in each project and default configuration are present on each "blueprint.xml file"

My Questions:
1 - Is there any other way to run swagger API on Multiple project using Apache Karaf ? 
2 - Is there any way we can permanently disable the caching using karaf/swagger Configuration  ? 
3 - Is there any method to clear swagger cache when i hit the "localhost:8181/cxf/api/api-docs" for each exposed services of multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here.

I've done some research on cxf [swagger2feature codebase](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/rs/description/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/swagger/SwaggerFeature.java) and it looks like it's not possible to have two swagger documentated APIs in a single container.

Comment: I researched a bit more on this…
Please refer the below JIRA issue -
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6740

please provide you suggestion

Comment: have you find something more on that ?

Comment: No. Swagger is not so important to me rigth now.